# Link Revit LT exported IFC to BlenderBIM Add-On

Tags: workflow, linked-data

Can one link an IFC file (specifically a building model assembled in and exported from Autodesk Revit **LT**) into Blender, or Blender w/ BlenderBim? And I mean "link," not import. I do not expect it to be live. But is there a workflow that would make updating possible? I feel I have researched and concluded this is still not possible, but am not experienced enough (ubernoob) to find a nuance other than simply re-importing and starting the scene and material editing again.

Background: I currently use the full version Revit and link into Twinmotion. I find it works well, but I feel the development we need to gravitate toward needs to be more open source. Our VR workflow needs to have less steps and more flexibility. All advice appreciated.

Can someone with better *reputation* add the tags "BlenderBim, IFC, BIM, & revit" to any response? My first question and I am not even trusted to understand tags.

Comment: As far as I know "live-linking" and auto-updating anything into Blender is not possible at the moment other than other .blend files themselves

Comment: BlenderBim by design modifies the IFC file directly, nothing of value is stored in the .blend. So the question is, can Revit LT import back the modified IFC file ? Maybe not suited for this site :) Since it's currently in Alpha state you may experience more engagement by posting an issue directly on the github page https://github.com/IfcOpenShell/IfcOpenShell/issues Cheers !

Comment: Btw I think the only new tag that would be nice would be `BIM`, usually tags pertain to workflows or blender modules, not to a particular add-on or software. But we do have tags for `archipack`, `Unity` and `fbx`, so who knows :) Don't hesitate to post a new thread on meta if you feel that's warranted https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You can also head over to https://community.osarch.org/ if you want to start a less formal conversation about your workflow

Comment: Brilliant. Advice deeply appreciated from all. I will have to get to work on my Python and make one then.